# Can we do atomic swap of lists in C#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, pointers, atomic

There are two lists: the first one contains a lot of large objects (large structures).

The second one should contain only a filtered subset of objects from the first list.

There's a thread which must continually go through the second list as quickly as possible. There's a second thread which does the filtering, because filtering is expensive and we don't want to disturb the first thread.

In C or C++, I'd do it like this:

- Make a flat array of structs / objects as the first list
- Make an array of pointers as the second list, and set up a common pointer to this array to be shared by both threads
- The thread which does the filtering would create a new array, fill it in with pointers to structs / objects in the first array, and then atomically swap the pointer to this array with the shared pointer
- The thread which examines the filtered elements will just examine the filtered list through the shared pointer. When the shared pointer is changed, it will just switch to the new list. Assuming that list lengths are not an issue and that appropriate atomic operations / memory barriers are in place.

Would that be possible at all in C#? If not, what would be the appropriate architecture?

Comment: Should the "going through" thread continue processing the original list if the "filtering thread" swaps the list out for a new list? OR if the "going through" thread has done 100 out of 200 items and a swap occurs shopuld it process item 101 from the new list?

Comment: Would it change anything? In this particular case, the going-through thread can just continue with element 101 of the new list of a swap occurs just before it would be reached in the old list.

Comment: I do something virtually identical to this - but instead of *pointers*, the filtered views are essentially `int[]` chunks which are the *offsets*; then I can just loop using that offset either from a pinned unmanaged pointer to the raw data, or using `Span<T>` with managed pointers - i.e. `ref Foo obj = ref span[index[i]];` - however, I wouldn't swap `index` *while anyone is using it*, because they need to know the lengths etc; I'd have them snapshot that (as a `Span<int>` probably) at the start of their run

Comment: I like it, integer offsets are just as good for my purpose!

Comment: "Would it change anything" - sure, I was thinking how I'd give the list to the worker to go through.. If you give the current reference to the list to the worker at the start of the work , and it goes away and works through it then it will keep the old list even if you swap it out for a new list. You're saying though that you want the list the worker is acting on to update instantly, so I guess it means the worker thread has to hit the list reference every time it ants something out the list, so if you do swap the list for something else, it realizes upon next access